# sum an array vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Formula to calculate the sum of visible columns.

```
Function SumVisible(WorkRng As Range) As Double

Dim rng As Range
Dim total As Double

For Each rng In WorkRng
    If rng.Rows.Hidden = False And rng.Columns.Hidden = False Then
        total = total + rng.Value
    End If
Next
SumVisible = total
End Function
```

This works fine for  a range such as `(A1:A3)` but I want to hide specific columns and calculate the sum:

`=SumVisible(I2,K2,M2,P2,S2,U2,AB2,Y2,AE2,AI2,AL2,AQ2,AS2,AV2)`

How can I loop over individual cells and add their total if they are visible??

Comment: You want to sum over only visible columns and rows?

Comment: yes i want to hide a column and the sum to change

Comment: What's wrong with SUBTOTAL or AGGREGATE to sum visible cells?

Comment: @jeeped they only work on rows and I need it to work on columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ct363x9h(v=vs.120)), it allows you to pass any number of arguments:

```
Function SumVisible(ParamArray WorkRng() As Variant) As Double
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim total As Double

    For i = LBound(WorkRng) To UBound(WorkRng)
        Set rng = WorkRng(i)
        For Each c In rng
            If c.Rows.Hidden = False And c.Columns.Hidden = False Then
                total = total + c.Value
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
    SumVisible = total
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
Public Function SumVisible(ByVal WorkRng As Range) As Double
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In WorkRng.Columns
        If Not col.EntireColumn.Hidden Then SumVisible = SumVisible + Application.WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(9, 7, col)
    Next col
End Function
```

---

Aggregate: You specify first the sum argument e.g. 9 for SUM, then the additional conditions argument e.g. 7 is Ignore hidden rows and error values.

Subtotal function can also be used which automatically ignore hidden rows.

You can view the argument lists here:

1. [AGGREGATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-aggregate-method-excel)
2. [SUBTOTAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-subtotal-method-excel)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that I wanted to hide the colums and not rows.. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Did you try the above?